# Setting the width of ColorColumn line in vim

Tags: vim

How can I change the width of the actual colorcolumn line?  Not how many characters offset the line appears, but the actual width of the line that shows up. Is there a way to do this?  Or am I stuck with a big bulky line when I set the option?

Comment: I don't get what you are asking.... colorcolumn is a column with hl color, not line. what is `the width of colorcolumn line`??

Comment: What info did you find when you did `:help colorcolumn`?

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted *more* width, you could specify multiple columns for the `'colorcolum'` option, or fall back to the previously needed emulations with `matchadd()` (e.g. to highlight everything until the end of the line).

But based on your complaint about the "big bulky line" I assume you want it smaller. Unfortunately, that goes against the design philosophy of Vim, see `:help design-not`:

> - Vim is not a fancy GUI editor that tries to look nice at the cost of
>     being less consistent over all platforms.  But functional GUI features are
>     welcomed.

In a terminal, a single screen cell is the smallest addressable unit. For consistency, the same is true in GVIM.